# How to enumerate all Grassmannian and it’s index and k and n in a table format?

Tags: macaulay2

Would like to enumerate all Grassmannian and its index and k and n
For Schubert function use

And how to Find the index
I find blog use

```
H^(0,0)
H^(1,1)
```

Until the number from ascending to descending
But it seems only return two numbers

Answer (score 0):

I guess you asked your question badly. I didn't understand it.
The Macaulay2's Schubert function takes k,n as input. Look here: [Grassmannian](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.12/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/___Grassmannian_lp__Z__Z_cm__Z__Z_rp.html)
and in Macaulay2 we use _ for indexing for example: `H_(i,j,k)`